# What happens to the running time of an $O(n \ln n)$ algorithm if you double $n$?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity

Problem:

Suppose the running time of a certain algorithm is $O(n \ln n)$. We happens to the running
time of the algorithm if $n$ doubles.

Answer:

Let $R_1$ be the running time of the algorithm when the input is of size $n$. Let $R_2$ be the running time of the algorithm when the input is of size $2n$. Let $R = R_2 / R_1$.
\begin{align*}
R &= \frac{ 2n \ln (2n)}{ n \ln n } =  \frac{ 2 \ln (2n)}{ \ln n } \\ 
R &= \frac{ 2 ( \ln(2) + \ln(n))}{ \ln n } =
    \frac{ 2 ( \ln(2) )}{ \ln n } + \frac{ 2 ( \ln(n))}{ \ln n }\\ 
R &= \frac{2 \ln(2)}{ \ln n } + 2 \\
\end{align*}
This does not seem right to me. Is it? If it is wrong, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Everything is correct: you obtain $O(1)$ factor. Which doubt you have?

Comment: Th way I see it, if this is correct then doubling $n$ when $n$ is large only causes about a factor of $2$ increase in the running time. That does not seem right to me, but I am starting to think it is.

Comment: Added answer. Let me bring as example simple linear search with $O(n)$ complexity. When we double input, then seems we "double" complexity, but it is same $O(n)$.

Comment: ln(n) doesn’t grow very fast if n is large. Yes, if you change n from a million to a trillion, n ln n grows by a million because of the factor n, and just an additional  factor 2 because of the ln n. In practice, n ln n behaves similar to O(n) with a much larger constant factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  suggest following property: if for functions $g,f \gt 0$ we have $f \sim kg$, for some constant $k\gt 0$  i.e. $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=k$ and both, $g$ and $f$, have not zero as limit point, then $O(f)=O(g)$.

**Proof:**

Let's consider $\phi \in  O(f)$, then we have $\phi \leqslant C f \leqslant C (k+\varepsilon)g$ for appropriate $C, \varepsilon$ and $n \gt N.$ So $O(f) \subset O(g)$. Using, that we have also $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}=\frac{1}{k} \gt 0$, we obtain reverse including.

Based on brought property we can say, that running time $O(n \ln n)$ does not change if we double $n$:
$$O(n \ln n) = O(2n \ln 2n)$$